# CSS: Make object-fit work with min-height

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to make `object-fit` work with `min-height`?

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6b28mr7/) for example.

If I set a fixed `height`, it works, but if I set a `min-height`, it doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="b_feat_img">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iEJWyXN.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width:120px;
}

.b_feat_img {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  min-height:130px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.b_feat_img img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the img container element to expand to full image height?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `min-height` needs to set on the `img` element, not the container.

In additional, you can also set `vertical-align:top` or `display:block` on the `img` to get rid of the unwanted whitespace below it.

```css
.container {
  width:120px;
}

.b_feat_img {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.b_feat_img img {
  object-fit: cover;
  min-height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="b_feat_img">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iEJWyXN.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `position: absolute` to the `img` in css.

So it will be like:
HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="b_feat_img">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iEJWyXN.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .container {
      width:120px;
    }

    .b_feat_img {
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid green;
      background: red;
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
      min-height:130px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .b_feat_img img {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
    }
```

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/b93txe6t/1/

Hope that helps.